# Adding JSON items to HTML using JQuery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Multiple buttons have category name (`data-bcategory`). When I click the button, based on that category value using ajax skills will display from the database. I have written a function which will return the JSON as below format. But in the view, I want to separate the category for each skill. I wrote each function and display skills value one by one but not for category. I think the solution is to write another each and display the category name. Please check the expected result and actual result.

HTML

```
<div class="modal-body" id="ajaxdisplayskills"> </div>
```

JQuery

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
  $(".boxselectcat").click(function () {
    var e = $(this).attr("data-bcategory")
    , l = $(this).attr("data-catgoid");
    $(".txtValueshwskillid").val(l), $.ajax({
     url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index/get_all_skills?category=" + e
     , type: "GET"
     , dataType: "json"
     , error: function () {
         $("#ajaxdisplayskills").append("<p>Some error please try again</p>")
     }
     , success: function (e) {
         $.each(e, function (e, l) {
            $("#ajaxdisplayskills").append('<label class="chkskills cursor1"><input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="' + l.id + '" />' + l.name + "</label>")
        })
      }
     })
    });
</script>
```

JSON

```
[
{
    "id": "95,100",
    "skill": "Car Washing,Sewage Cleaning",
    "sub_cat": "Cleaning"
},
{
    "id": "292",
    "skill": "Furniture Installation",
    "sub_cat": "Maintenance"
}
]
```

Actual Result

```
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="95">Car Washing</label>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="100">Sewage Cleaning</label>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="292">Furniture Installation</label>
```

Expected Result

```
<h4 class="signup-sub-cat">Cleaning</h4>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="95">Car Washing</label>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="100">Sewage Cleaning</label>
<h4 class="signup-sub-cat">Maintenance</h4>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="292">Furniture Installation</label>
```

Comment: What is the question? And what have you tried? Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: Please check the expected result and actual results. I want to display the category name.

Comment: That is your goal..sure. But that isn't a code specific problem. Are you suggesting that you want someone to write all this for you?

Comment: Yes please help me to fix this. I tried my best level. But couldn't get the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use two functions to archive your goal.

First, you have to use `each` function to separate the category. Then use `forloop` to display all skills under those category.

Comment: Thanks @user7152572, I found the answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

```
$.each(e, function (e, l) {
 $("#ajaxdisplayskills").append('<h4 class="signup-sub-cat">' + l.sub_cat + '</h4>');
 var skill_name = l.skill.split(',');
 var skill_id = l.id.split(',');
 var q;
 for (q = 0; q < skill_name.length; q++){
      $("#ajaxdisplayskills").append('<label class="chkskills cursor1"><input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="' + skill_id[q] + '" />' + skill_name[q] + "</label>");
      }
 })
```